# OpenLayers Pie Chart

Tags: openlayers-3

How to integrate pie chart on Openlayers? Tried implementing the same using OPenlayer style circle, but the circle can't be converted into a semi circle and hence can't be placed as a chart
Please provide suitable examples for the same.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you take a look at `ol3-ext` here: https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext

**Examples:**

1. Simple Pie chart: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.chart.html
2. Chart with values: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.chart+text.html

Comment: Hi, kaycee, the URLs you posted are all 404. Do you have more references?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I didn't find a suitable solution for myself, so I created my own function for generating diagrams. It is very simple and easily customizable. For your convenience, I have packaged my solution as an open-source project. https://github.com/kossyak/olStyleChart